# Extract hourly values ( and its indexes) that exceeds monthly averages in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two data frames. df and df1. Both data files are big (cover data since 01-01-200 up to 31-10-2019) so I just uploaded a small sample.

df contains hourly values of 3 variables and its corresponding date vector, like this:

```
           date           SH1          SH2         SH3        
     2000-01-01 00:00:00 1.941013e-01 1.506780e-01 0.124487891 
     2000-01-01 03:00:00 2.897915e-01 2.743722e-01 0.188432490 
     2000-01-01 06:00:00 3.139408e-01 2.250532e-01 0.001473900 
     2000-01-01 09:00:00 1.845777e-01 1.041934e-01 0.047391565 
     2000-01-01 12:00:00 1.022660e-01 6.179044e-02 0.008843402 
     

df <- structure(list(datex = structure(c(946681200, 946692000, 946702800, 
946713600, 946724400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), SH1 = c(0.194101337780203, 
0.289791483274648, 0.313940773547535, 0.184577674010614, 0.102266008573448
), SH2 = c(0.150677966068861, 0.274372218123884, 0.225053245031368, 
0.104193416717294, 0.0617904375526934), SH3 = c(0.12448789070249, 
0.188432490298304, 0.00147390034529415, 0.0473915649486711, 0.00884340207176182
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

While df1 is the monthly average (per year) of the same data. Looks like this:

```
      date       SH1       SH2       SH3       
  2000-01-01 0.7733497 0.6237698 0.4182768 
  2000-02-01 0.7308772 0.5575175 0.3636893  
  2000-03-01 0.3278784 0.3040463 0.2233942  
  2000-04-01 0.4496596 0.3124064 0.1805953  
  2000-05-01 0.4500503 0.4032727 0.2562054  

df1 <- structure(list(datex = structure(c(10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 
11078), class = "Date"), SH1 = c(0.773349659462019, 0.730877175434939, 
0.327878366545974, 0.44965959591958, 0.450050258753037), SH2 = c(0.623769804010216, 
0.557517466419755, 0.304046348866025, 0.312406405495768, 0.403272666559865
), SH3 = c(0.418276825782115, 0.36368930844493, 0.223394192812674, 
0.18059530865458, 0.256205390604878)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to extract the values in df that exceed their corresponding monthly average (df1) and also get the location (index) of such values. How can I achieve this? I'm not an expert in R so please be patient.

I believe that the comparison must be made based on the year and month in both data sets but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Would help if you made these examples reproducible: you could use `dput()`...

Comment: I have edited the question and added the results from `dput()`

Comment: One thing with `data.table` is that you need to remove the part `.internal.selfref = ...`. after every dput.

Comment: Also: in what format do you want to the outcome?

Comment: edited, I have deleted the `internal.selfref-..` part. I don't mind if the result is a data frame or data table, both could work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something in this way:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(year = year(date), month = month(date)) %>% 
  mutate(
    monthly_average_SH1 = mean(SH1),
    monthly_average_SH2 = mean(SH2),
    monthly_average_SH3 = mean(SH3),
    flag_exceed_SH1 = ifelse(SH1 > monthly_average_SH1, TRUE, FALSE),
    flag_exceed_SH2 = ifelse(SH2 > monthly_average_SH2, TRUE, FALSE),
    flag_exceed_SH3 = ifelse(SH3 > monthly_average_SH3, TRUE, FALSE),
    flag_any_exceed = ifelse(flag_exceed_SH1 | flag_exceed_SH2 | flag_exceed_SH3, TRUE, FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  filter(flag_any_exceed)
```

This will give you a df with all the lines that exceeded the value. Note that df1 was not necessary, because you can generate the means on the same df.

If you want the indexes:

```
df_2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(year = year(date), month = month(date)) %>% 
  mutate(
    monthly_average_SH1 = mean(SH1),
    monthly_average_SH2 = mean(SH2),
    monthly_average_SH3 = mean(SH3),
    flag_exceed_SH1 = ifelse(SH1 > monthly_average_SH1, TRUE, FALSE),
    flag_exceed_SH2 = ifelse(SH2 > monthly_average_SH2, TRUE, FALSE),
    flag_exceed_SH3 = ifelse(SH3 > monthly_average_SH3, TRUE, FALSE),
    flag_any_exceed = ifelse(flag_exceed_SH1 | flag_exceed_SH2 | flag_exceed_SH3, TRUE, FALSE)
  ) 
which(df2$flag_any_exceed)
```

Hope this is usefull

Comment: How can I do this in a more effective way if I have more columns instead of 3?

Comment: you could use dplyr across function I suppose.